# How to prove that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\log n]}}{n}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\log n]}}{n}$ diverges?
I've tried something with the following $$\log n - 1 <[\log n] \leq \log n$$ but I haven't got anything from that. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Answers my question as to what log with brackets around it means.

Comment: @MAPelto it is probably the floor function (old notation, now we prefer $\lfloor x\rfloor$).

Comment: Yes, a solution is found in @zwim's link.